# Getting value from a twig to a controller

Tags: symfony, controller, twig

I'm using Symfony2 and my view is a twig/php. Can I get a value from a view? I tried like this: 
**listcurrency.twig.html:**

```
{% for currency in liste %}

                <TR> 
                <TH> <a href="{{ path('devises_disable', { 'id': currency.id }) }}"> {{currency.id}} </TH> 
                <TD>  {{ currency.Name}}  </TD> 
                <TD>  {{currency.Enabled}}</TD>

                </TR> 
                {% endfor %}
```

I call a route `'devises_disable'` and pass a parameter `currency.id`.

EDIT:this is what i do with the value:

**controller:**

```
public function disableAction($id)
    {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $currency = $em->getRepository('DevisesBundle:Currency')->findOneById($id);
        if (!$currency) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'Aucun currency trouvée pour cet id : '.$id
        );
    }
         $i=$currency->getEnabled();
         if($i==0){$i=1;}else if($i==1){$i=0;}
         $currency->setEnabled($i);
         $em->flush();
         $em->refresh($currency);

    }
```

**the route:**

```
 devises_disable:
        path: /webmaster/listcurrency
        defaults: {_controller: DevisesBundle:Default:disable}
```

the entity i'm trying to update doesn't change.No error message too!!

Comment: OK, you should probably also explain the way it doesn't work, specifically.

Comment: Please post your route for `devises_disable`

Comment: i did,hope it can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your route into :

```
devises_disable:
        path: /webmaster/listcurrency/{id}
        defaults: {_controller: DevisesBundle:Default:disable}
```

For checking the variable success or not passed into your controller put this in top of your controller :
`echo 'This is the variable : '.$id`;

Comment: It's exactly what i did minutes before i read your answer.thanks a lot.